# Glut/Glu alternatives on OSX 10.9 for drawing primitives like spheres

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, opengl

I decided to do some OpenGL programming on OSX. I created a small NSOpenGLView class in order for me to get an OpenGL view in cocoa.

From there my plan was to switch to C++ and create an object model to draw shapes. Having no interest in reinventing the wheel I decided to use `glutWireSphere` to represent my sphere class. 
Interestingly XCode throws a deprecation warning for ~90% of all the glu and glut functions. Including the sphere function.

Is there an Apple library that provides primitives similar to Glut? Am I missing something? Is there a current HowTo for OpenGL programming on OSX (OpenGL >= 3.2)? I'm currently looking through the OpenGL Programming Guide for Mac but that doesn't seem to cover it. Googling it mostly returns IOS or old results.

Note: I don't want to force the compilation to 10.8. And I don't necessarily want to link external libraries like GLFW.

Comment: A quick search for "OpenGL sphere without glut" turned up [this tutorial](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/sphere.html).

Comment: @user1118321 : Yes I saw these as well (in various forms). I guess this is the way to go then.

Comment: The main (poorly documented) thing to remember about programming modern GLUT on OSX is to specify GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE to get an OpenGL 4.1 context.  It stinks compute shaders aren't supported, but there are some good extensions and 4.1 is the latest version supported in El Capitan.  As for the deprecated warnings, I typically just delete those macros from the system headers.

Comment: Actually I started working on a C++ codebase that wraps OpenGL 4.1 with classes and templates. Its still a work in progress and very hacky, but if you are interested you can have a look at it here: https://github.com/pspoerri/NothingSpecial . Right now it supports obj files and 3d volumes. I'm also going to re-license to BSD it once it is in a more polished state. The OpenGL part was taken from https://github.com/karhu/terrain-erosion where I was involved a couple years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [**SceneKit**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/SceneKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) if you can use 10.9+. It's a native Cocoa framework specifically designed for dealing with 3D rendering.

From the docs:

> '*Scene Kit is a 3D-rendering Objective-C framework that combines a
>   high-performance rendering engine with a high-level, descriptive API.
>   Scene Kit supports the import, manipulation, and rendering of 3D
>   assets without requiring the exact steps to render a scene the way
>   OpenGL does.*'

In particular the [`SCNSphere`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSphere_Class/Reference/SCNSphere.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012019) class is what you'll be looking for.

And here's a nice scene kit intro by [Big Nerd Ranch](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/):
[**SceneKit in Mountain Lion**](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/754-scenekit-in-mountain-lion/)

**However**, one thing to consider is that you'll end up with code that is not portable to other platforms as SceneKit is native to OS X (and eventually iOS). Frameworks like OpenGL, [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/), [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) on the other hand support many different desktop and mobile platforms.

Comment: Oh wow. That's exactly something I was looking for! But you're right: It doesn't seem to be portable.

Comment: Hope it suits your purposes - in either case, it's more modern than the OpenGL APIs so should be more fun to use.